# Are there any examples where we *need* protected inheritance in C++?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

While I've seen rare cases where *private* inheritance was needed, I've never encountered a case where *protected* inheritance is needed. Does someone have an example?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

People here seem to mistake Protected class inheritance and Protected methods.

FWIW, I've never seen anyone use protected class inheritance, and if I remember correctly I think Stroustrup even considered the "protected" level to be a mistake in c++. There's precious little you cannot do if you remove that protection level and only rely on public and private.

Comment: Just a quick comment: Mr. C++'s surname is Stroustrup ;)

Comment: Good Lord, I'll fix it immediately! :)

Answer (score 5):

There is a very rare use case of protected inheritance. It is where you want to make use of [covariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29):

```
struct base { 
    virtual ~base() {} 
    virtual base & getBase() = 0;
}; 

struct d1 : private /* protected */ base { 
    virtual base & getBase() { 
        return this; 
    } 
}; 

struct d2 : private /* protected */ d1 {
    virtual d1 & getBase () { 
        return this; 
    } 
};
```

The previous snippet tried to hide it's base class, and provide controlled visibility of bases and their functions, for whatever reason, by providing a "getBase" function.

However, it will fail in struct `d2`, since `d2` does not know that `d1` is derived from `base`. Thus, `covariance` will not work. A way out of this is deriving them protected, so that the inheritance is visible in d2.

A similar example of using this is when you derive from `std::ostream`, but don't want random people to write into your stream. You can provide a virtual `getStream` function that returns `std::ostream&`. That function could do some preparing of the stream for the next operation. For example putting certain manipulators in.

```
std::ostream& d2::getStream() {
    this->width(10);
    return *this;
}

logger.getStream() << "we are padded";
```

Answer (score 1):

[C++ FAQ Lite](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/) mentions of a case where using private inheritance is a legitimate solution (See [[24.3.] Which should I prefer: composition or private inheritance?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/private-inheritance.html#faq-24.3)). It's when you want to call the derived class from within a private base class through a virtual function (in this case `derivedFunction()`):

```
class SomeImplementationClass
{
protected:
    void service() {
        derivedFunction();
    }

    virtual void derivedFunction() = 0;      

    // virtual destructor etc
};

class Derived : private SomeImplementationClass
{
    void someFunction() {
        service();
    }

    virtual void derivedFunction() {
        // ...
    }

    // ...
};
```

Now if you want to derive from the class Derived, and you want to use `Base::service()` from within the derived class (say you want to move `Derived::someFunction()` to the derived class), the easiest way to accomplish this is to change the private inheritance of `Base` to protected inheritance.

Sorry, can't think of a more concrete example. Personally I like to make all inheritance public so as to avoid wasting time with "should I make inheritance relation protected or private" discussions.

Comment: but that's not what the poster asked about, he asked about protected inheritance. There are certainly cases where you would want private inheritance, albeit not too many.